# Why do multiple clauses in the $or operator messes up the 'text' index?

Tags: mongodb

Please examine this query:

```js
db.getCollection('tasks').find({
  $text: {$search: "anything"},
  $or: [
    {tags: 'tag'},
    {'collaborators._id': 'id'}
  ]
})
.explain("executionStats");
```

The resulting explanation of this query states, that the winning plan is FETCH; whereas if I remove any one of the entries in the `$or` operator, then the winning plan becomes TEXT.

The expected behavior is that using this query, the runner would not end up using FETCH, because we have a huge database with big documents, so FETCH is killing our DB.

---

There are the following indexes:

```
[
  //...
  {
    "key": {
      "_fts": "text",
      "_ftsx": 1,
      "collaborators._id": 1,
      "tags": 1
    },
    "weights": {
      "comments.text": 1,
      "title": 3
    },
    "language_override": "language",
    "default_language": "english",
    "textIndexVersion": 3
  },
  {
    "key": {
      "collaborators._id": 1
    },
  },
  {
    "key": {
      "tags": 1
    },
  },
  //...
]
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: can you please post your complete `getIndexes()` data, including `name` and `ns` for each key(s)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/JivDGd2U here it is